# How to find count of word in Java 8

Tags: java, string, java-8, counting

I'm having below sentence

```
Hello world Hello Stackoverflow
```

Expected output: (order is not concern)

```
{2=[Hello], 1=[world,Stackoverflow]}
```

Tried with below code:

```
        final String input = "Hello world Hello Stackoverflow";

        final Map<String, Long> output = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(output);
```

got below output:

```
{world=1, Hello=2, Stackoverflow=1}
```

I want to get `Long` as key and `List<String>` as value in Map

How to do this?

Comment: The keys in a `Map` are unique. So there is no way to get a `Map` that looks like `{2=Hello, 1=world, 1=Stackoverflow}` where there are two entries with the key `1`.

Comment: Keys in hashmap must be unique, soyou cant get output like this {2=Hello, 1=world, 1=Stackoverflow}

Comment: edited my question. How can we get Map<Long,List<String>>?

Comment: @Remo `{2=Hello, 1=[world,Stackoverflow]}`  This is `Long, String` and then `Long, List<String>` in a single Map, the first one would still need to be a `List` of size 1.

Comment: edited, expected is {2=[Hello], 1=[world,Stackoverflow]}. output type Map<Long,List<String>

Answer (score 4):

You need to group the Map entries like this :

```java
String input = "Hello world Hello Stackoverflow";

Map<Long, List<String>> output = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet() // Set<Entry<String, Long>>
    .stream() // Stream<Entry<String, Long>>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      Map.Entry::getValue, 
      Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
    ));

System.out.println(output); // {1=[world, Stackoverflow], 2=[Hello]}
```

Comment: is it possible to do in single stream?

Comment: I don't see any simple solution with a single stream. I would suggest to create your own Collector but I prefer the solution with two streams

Comment: Building a hash map to determine the actual word count, is the most efficient way to do it. Doing something “in a single stream” is not a useful goal.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to do in single stream?

Not really (or probably not as efficiently).  You need to have the frequency of each word to use as a key.  Continually updating the key during map construction is fraught with problems. And you would need to update the lists as well.

However, the following does the exact same thing but without a stream.  So it is probably a little more efficient. And you can use your just created map as the source.

- create a destination map.
- iterate over the entrySet
- `computeIfAbsent` will create the list if the key is not present.
- it also returns the just created or existing value, a list in this case, so you can add the word.

```
Map<Long, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String,Long> e : output.entrySet()) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(), v->new ArrayList<>())
            .add(e.getKey());
}

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1=[world, Stackoverflow]
2=[Hello]
```

Comment: why do you think it would be more efficient ?

Comment: Streams are inherrently inefficient due to their overhead. That doesn't mean they aren't useful and there is nothing at all wrong with your solution (I have used a similar one many times)  And it's probably a matter of degree depending on what you are doing.

Comment: `output.forEach((k,v) -> result.computeIfAbsent(v, v1 -> new ArrayList<>()).add(k));` would do as well.